# Obtaining the sum of several elements listed in a geojson

Tags: python-3.x, sentinelsat

I apologize if this question has been asked or answered elsewhere before. I couldn't locate it.

I'm still relatively new to python and I'm currently setting up a script for downloading files from the ESA sentinel hub via the sentinelsat module.

Now it is working, but I'd like for it to have a way of printing the total file size involved. I already have it printing the name of all the files and their individual data sizes. I also have the total number of files listed. Now I just need the individual data sizes summed into 1 value..

So here is my code snippet:

```html
print("Listing file name and size:")
print("")
for n in range(0, np.size(bu_images_json["features"])):
    print("Image name: ",json.dumps(bu_images_json["features"][n]["properties"]["title"]))
    print("File size: ",json.dumps(bu_images_json["features"][n]["properties"]["size"]))
print("Found", n+1, "files availible for download")
print("Total amount to download")
```

And it looks something like this

```html
Image name:  "S2A_OPER_PRD_MSIL1C_PDMC_20161009T061329_R010_V20160727T140022_20160727T140246"
File size:  "5.02 GB"
Image name:  "S2A_OPER_PRD_MSIL1C_PDMC_20161009T060351_R139_V20160726T142942_20160726T143122"
File size:  "5.99 GB"
Image name:  "S2A_OPER_PRD_MSIL1C_PDMC_20160720T213054_R053_V20160720T141008_20160720T141008"
File size:  "5.65 GB"
Found 131 files availible for download
Total amount to download
```

If anyone is aware of any github page or the likes, of which anyone has played around with and expanded the sentinelsat module - Then I'd love to have a link as well.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from re import sub
print("Listing file name and size:")
total = 0
print("")
for n in range(0, np.size(bu_images_json["features"])):
    print("Image name: ",json.dumps(bu_images_json["features"][n]["properties"]["title"]))
    print("File size: ",json.dumps(bu_images_json["features"][n]["properties"]["size"]))
    total += float(sub('[^0-9.]','',json.dumps(bu_images_json["features"][n]["properties"]["size"])))
print("Found", n+1, "files availible for download")
print("Total amount to download: ",total)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) 

However I get this error:

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '"193.48'

Comment: @Kongie I just edited it. There was a missing parenthesis. Now try it again

Comment: I found the missing parenthesis. However still getting that error :o

Comment: Image name:  "S2A_MSIL1C_20160905T140012_N0204_R010_T24WWU_20160905T140241"
File size:  "193.48 MB"

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-32-c2ecaa64c184>", line 36, in <module>
    total += float(sub(r'(?<=\d)\s.*','',json.dumps(bu_images_json["features"][n]["properties"]["size"])))

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '"193.48'

Comment: change `r'(?<=\d)\s.*'` to `[^0-9.]` and try again

Comment: total += float([^0-9.],'',json.dumps(bu_images_json["features"][n]["properties"]["size"])))
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: no, you were supposed to replace the `r'(?<=\d)\s.*'` part only ie: `float(sub('[^0-9.]','',json.dumps(b...`

Comment: `float(sub('[^0-9.]','',json.dumps(bu_images_json["features"][n]["properties"]["size"])))`

Comment: Now I have you here, is there an easy way to shorten down how many decimals that are given in the print ;)

Comment: just use `round(total, 2)` for 2 decimals, 3 for 3decimals etc